# JSON return values choice

Tags: json

I have a question. My api return dictionary with object Pupils. Is it good choice? Or better choice is return ids and then you download list od object(key is id) then you connect it on front-end?

Comment: Both may be ok, it depends on your data. It is a design choice, not a technical question.

Comment: Object Pupil has firstname, lastname, class, dare of birthday. What about if you have a lot of data what is faster?

Comment: If you need to pass this data, you need to pass the whole Pupil object. Are you only trying to do a search by name, id etc? And then another request for the single item?

Comment: For example api would return id, then you would have another task for download list of pupils, then you connect it on front-end with id

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you implement different types of requests within your API.

1) searches. These can contain less information, for example id and/or name. They will help narrow down queries and return only helpful data. For example a search by ids can return the names or viceversa.

2) queries. after having narrowed down with a search, send these to get the full data, only the entries you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

contextually, it would be better to do the former way. Which I assume is this:

```
{  
   "pupils":[  
      {  
         "id":12,
         "name":"pupil1"
      },
      {  
         "id":13,
         "name":"pupil2"
      }
   ]
}
```

That way, the consumer of the json (be it frontend or any other service) will recognise the intent of the object straight away